# VS TACO error "Cannot find the app installed on the device" on iOS device

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I'm using VS2015 Update 2 with TACO Update 9 and I'm attempting to debug an application on a iPhone 6S (iOS 9.3.1) attached to my Windows computer. The remote build is successful but I get the following messages when it attempts to debug the app:

```
2>------ Deploy started: Project: xyz, Configuration: Debug iOS ------
2>Found iTunes version: 12.3.0.44
2>Uninstalling app ID:  com.bob.xyz.
2>Successfully installed .ipa file:  D:\Documents\Projects\xyz\xyz\bin\iOS\Debug\xyz.ipa.
2>Starting idevicedebugserverproxy.exe at port 3000.
2>Cannot find the app installed on the device. Check that the device is connected, awake, and unlocked.
2>Deployment failed.
```

When I look on the device, I do not see the application. Are there steps I can take to further debug what might be causing the failure?

Comment: Based on your log file, the app should be installed, however you should need to unlock some permissions in settings. Are you able to deploy a sample app from XCode. Check this document https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/

Comment: I get the same thing. My iphone is attached, unlocked, awake, iTunes is open, etc. I can manually copy the same IPA via iTunes to my iPhone, but it seems like the build starts this process then fails somewhere and doesn't explain why it failed.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your solution is configured for Debug build and not Release.